# Micro services vs web services

Tags: java, xml, apache, web-services, microservices

What is the exactly difference between Micro services vs web services.

My requirement is need to link up web services(SOAP,REST) service to micro services.

Can i consider micro services also web services.

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Micro services are a "design" pattern that guides *how* you implement functionality. "Web services" on the other hand focus on how customers consume services.

In that sense, these two concepts are completely orthogonal. You can provide a REST / SOAP interface to your clients - and internally, this REST endpoint is implemented as micro service ... or as just one thing within a huge monolith.

Comment: My question is how can  we call my web services(SOAP,REST) in miro service design pattern .How we will found difference, you mean to say is this wrong..

Comment: Again: micro services describe how you provide functionality, that is based on different services. That has *nothing* to do with REST or SOAP.