# What is main difference between microservices, web-services and api?

Tags: web-services, microservices

Microservice Vs Web Service, Api what is the main difference among these

Comment: Please check this url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48984610/micro-services-vs-web-services

Answer (score 0):

**API** - It a way of exposing functionality over web. Imagine you have developed some functionality in .Net but not you are developing some software in a different language. Would you develop the same functionality again? No. So, just expose it via web service.Web services are not tied to any one operating system or programming language. For example, an application developed in Java can communicate with the one developed in C#, Android, etc., and vice versa.

**Microservice** - They are used to break a complex software into small pieces of individually deployable, testable, loosely coupled sub-modules. Micro Services are designed to cope with failure and breakdowns of large applications. Since multiple unique services are communicating together, it may happen that a particular service fails, but the overall larger applications remain unaffected by the failure of a single module.

**API Vs Microservice** - Now that we have broken our complex software into loosely couple sub-modules. These sub-modules communicate with each other via an API. Therefore, Microservices and an API solve different problems but works together!